# KeboardAvoidingView not working on standalone app [React Native Expo]

Tags: react-native, jsx

The KeyBoardAvoidingView is working fine in the expo testing but when i build a stand alone app it does not work at all.

PS: i am using react navigation but the header is set to null.

KeyBoardAvoidingView Usage Code

```
   <KeyboardAvoidingView  behavior='padding'>
              <TextInput style={styles.formTextInput}
                onChangeText={this.emailOnChange}
                value={this.state.email}
                placeholder={'Email...'}
                onSubmitEditing={() => { this.secondTextInput.focus(); }}
                blurOnSubmit={false}
                autoCapitalize='none'
                returnKeyType='next'
                keyboardType='email-address'
              />
              <TextInput style={styles.formTextInput}
                onChangeText={this.passwordOnChange}
                value={this.state.password}
                ref={(input) => { this.secondTextInput = input; }}
                password={true}
                secureTextEntry={true}
                placeholder={'Password...'}
                maxLength={20}
                autoCapitalize='none'
              />
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

[image: expo app preview]

[image: Stand alone app preview]

Comment: One thing I can point out is you are not setting flex at the KeyboardAvoiding 
also padding behavior does not play nicely at android, you need to adjust that to be Platform specific.

Comment: Hi @Salim did you find solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this one,

```
import {
    View,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    ScrollView,
    Platform,
  } from "react-native";
  
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <KeyboardAvoidingView
    behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : null}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    enabled
  >
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
      <EmailField />
      <PasswordField />
    </ScrollView>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</View>
```

Customize your TextInputs